# IPTABLES ban ip if more than X conn per second

Tags: iptables, firewall, ip

I'm creating a small firewall with iptables that limits the max simultaneous connections per IP to 40.

So this is my situation:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --syn --dport 1234 -m connlimit --connlimit-above 40 -j REJECT --reject-with tcp-reset
```

If the number of connections per IP is above 40, i would like to ban this IP for 120 seconds, but i don't see a way to do this.

Can someone help me?

Comment: Your question title and body are actually in conflict. Which of these you want: A) reject all new connections from an IP for 120 secs if that IP has already more than 40 connections; B) reject (all new) connections from an IP the there are more than X (new?) connections per second ?

Comment: Take a look at this https://github.com/jgmdev/ddos-deflate :-)

Answer (score 0):

You could use [fail2ban](http://www.fail2ban.org) for the banning part after the connection limit is exceeded. I think it is not possible to combine `connlimit` and `recent` modules (`recent` would otherwise be natural choice for anything time-interval based rules) so that they would fulfil your banning requirement.